# Как использовать структуру, которая была объявлена в другой функции? GO

Tags: golang

Начинаю учить языки со статической типизацией. После динамической просто вынос мозга. Пишу веб-сервер на GO. У меня есть 2 функции (пример ниже), могу ли я объявить структуру в одной, а использовать в другой? Мой пример (он не работает)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

// эта функция неизменна и переиспользуется, поэтому я не могу объявлять структуру в ней
func getRequestData(Form type) {
    /*
    Здесь должен быть обработчик запроса. Он берёт json из запроса,
    заносит данные в структуру и возвращает её, что-то типа:
    */
    var form Form
    jsonString := `{"username": "admin", "password": "1234"}`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &form)
    return form
}

func main() {
    type loginForm struct {
        username string
        password string
    }
    data := getRequestData(loginForm)
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Короткий ответ: да, можно, но только через reflection.

Длинный ответ.

В Go есть два механизма работы со значениям - статическая типизация и reflection.

В выражении `json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &form)` используется именно reflection. Метод `Unmarshal` в динамике добудет описание фактического типа переменной form, узнает имена, типы и смещения полей относительно начала значения, и заполнит их десереализованными значениями. Этому методу нет разницы, где именно объявлен тип переменной `form`, ибо с этим типом метод работает в динамике.

Но! До того, как дело дойдет до `Unmarshal`, компилятор должен обработать вызов функции `getRequestData`, и на этом ваш код безнадёжно сломается.

Имена типов в Go не являются идентификаторами объектов. Ключевое слово `type` нельзя использовать в описании параметра. Параметр функции не может быть типом, имя параметра нельзя использовать как имя типа при объявлении переменной.

Добиться того, что вам нужно, можно с типом `interface{}`. Этот тип в Go обозначает *произвольный тип*

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
)

func getRequestData() interface{} {
    var form interface{}
    jsonString := `{"username": "admin", "password": "1234"}`
    json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), &form)
    return form
}

func main() {
    type loginForm struct {
        username string
        password string
    }
    data := getRequestData()
    fmt.Println(data)
}
```

Такая функция извлечёт данные из строки и сохранит их в `map`. Поля json структуры будут доступны как ключи в отображении: `data["username"]` и `data["password"]`

Однако, забавная особенность `json.Unmarshal` в том, что эта функция полностью соответствует динамической типизации. Она сама проверит состав полей в структуре-параметре и постарается её корректно восстановить из JSON.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func getRequestData(form interface{}) error {
    jsonString := `{"username": "admin", "password": "1234"}`
    // json.Unmarshal сам увидит, как устроена структура form, 
    // и постарается её корректно восстановить
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), form)
}

type LoginData struct {
    Username string
    Password string
}

func main() {
    var form LoginData
    err := getRequestData(&form)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(form)
}
```

Вам достаточно передать указатель на ожидаемую структуру и проверить возвращаемую ошибку.

UPD.

Отвечая на исходный вопрос. Так как `json.Unmarshal` работает со значениями через reflection, то эта функция работает с любыми типами, объявленными где угодно.

В моём ответе `LoginData` вынесена на уровень пакета (и это кошерно), но можно было бы объявить тип внутри функции (хоть это и неправославно). Сработает. Главное, поля поименовать с большой буквы, иначе их через reflection нельзя изменить, и go их проигнорирует.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

func getRequestData(form interface{}) error {
    jsonString := `{"username": "admin", "password": "1234"}`
    // json.Unmarshal сам увидит, как устроена структура form,
    // и постарается её корректно восстановить
    return json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonString), form)
}

func main() {
    type LoginData struct {
        Username string
        Password string
    }

    var form LoginData
    err := getRequestData(&form)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(form)
}
```

Comment: Приколы то с интерфейсами я видел, знаю что можно map использовать, но тогда у меня не получается фильтровать запросы и требовать соответствие определённых полей определённым типам, например, мне нужно чтобы в запросе был передан id типа integer. Я хочу создать нужную структуру и парсить json в неё, если возникает ошибка - значит неверные поля были переданы в запросе, может я могу как-то указатель передать на созданный мною тип?

Comment: @Inventor, я добавил пример с динамической типизацией объектов в `json.Unmarshal`

Comment: Да, всё работает, только один вопрос, почему в случае, когда поля в структуре начинаются с маленькой буквы их значение становится `null`?

Comment: @Inventor Соглашение о видимости в go - поля с маленькой буквы считаются приватными (более точно, unexported) и недоступны вне области видимости, в которой определён тип. В частности, reflection не может писать в такие поля, и они остаются в том же состоянии, в каком были инциализированы. Если вы инциализировали структуру пустым значением, то строковые поля инициализировались значением `nil`.